# Objective c (ios) Call method automatically to an hour each day

Tags: objective-c

good afternoon. 
I need your support, please. 
Should I call a method every day at a time. (9:00 PM, 9:00 PM 1:00 PM, etc) 
This should be Automatically But, even the application is closed. 
Have an idea? 
I would try a NSTimer but I doubt that will work if the application is closed.

I hope your help please! 
THANK YOU. 
Excuse my Inglés is not very good.

--
Details 
I need to call a web service that is contained in a method from time to time. Automatically
This is native ios

Comment: You will have to add more details on what you have tried so far: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: is this for ios or osx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only care about iOS7, as Wain wrote, you could try a silent push notification or the new ability to update your app in the background. Check out this guide, hopefully it will help you do what you want to do:

[Updating an Application in the Background](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/backgrounding/part_3_ios_backgrounding_techniques/updating_an_application_in_the_background/)

Comment: Ok, Thank you. Nexon. I really want to do is to call a method that contains a call to a web service.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a timer, at least not without cheating.

If you want to alert the user to something, use `UILocalNotification`.

If you want to run some code and then alert the user, and you only care about iOS 7, use a (silent) push notification with fetch.

Comment: Ok, wain. I will try to UILocalNotification. 
thank you very much